# Nested If statement doesn't return the last 'value if false' of the last if clause

Tags: excel-formula

My question is regarding a simple excel if function. I want a cell value to be dependent on the content of 2 cells ; if they both have values, the cell has a determined value, if one has value and the other is empty, the cell has another value (depending on which on is empty) and finally if both are empty the cell should be empty.

I made the function and it works with all 3 situation except the last argument where both are empty, the cell keeps a value as if they both have values.

```
=IF(AND(F12="";NOT(ISBLANK(F11)));E7*258.78;IF(AND(F11="";NOT(ISBLANK(F12)));E7*232.9;IF(NOT(ISBLANK(AND(F11;F12)));E7*491.68;"")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inverted `AND` and `ISBLANK` at the end

```
=IF(AND(F12="";NOT(ISBLANK(F11)));E7*258.78;IF(AND(F11="";NOT(ISBLANK(F12)));E7*232.9;IF(NOT(AND(ISBLANK(F11);ISBLANK(F12)));E7*491.68;"")))
```

Comment: It works! thank you sir!
I felt like it's gonna be just a stupid mistake.